# Dynamic HTML 3 layers nested quotes - how to do?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, html-lists

I'm writing an app with JQuery & JQTouch fo iOS. I have a dynamically generated HTML list. The user clicks a row, which I need to highlight. However, this involves nesting 3 sets of quotes, which I can't figure out how to do! (I have it working using JQuery, but I'm hoping it'll be more efficient inline as it's only a small CSS change). My code is:

```
CURRENT_answerHTML += '<li id="1" onClick="this.className=nmclicked">' + localResultsArray[currentQuestionNumber].answer1_text + '</li>\n';
```

`nmclicked` needs to be in quotes as far as I'm aware, but no combination of escaping seems to work. The CSS is straighforward:

```
li.nmclicked { background: #5C94E7; }
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Your approach works, and @davin has the answer to solve your question, but note that you should not be generating HTML as a string, nor embedding JavaScript event handlers in your HTML. (Also, your `id` attribute is illegal, as it cannot start with a number and must be unique.) Use DOM manipulation to create new elements and use `addEventListener` to attach event handlers to DOM nodes.

Comment: @Phrogz, I agree with everything you said as far as what *should* be done according to the standards, although there is still the consideration that markup in a string (plain html, not event handlers which make JS code less maintainable if they're embedded in a string) vs. standard DOM manipulation, is soooo much quicker, and often makes code more readable/maintainable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CURRENT_answerHTML += '<li id="1" onClick="this.className=\'nmclicked\'">' + localResultsArray[currentQuestionNumber].answer1_text + '</li>\n';
```